# How to merge two collections on a field using aggregation pipelines in pymongo where the field of one collection has to be edited using regex first

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I have two collections: a `ratings` collection and an `episodes` collection. The `ratings` collection has a field `tconst` which would be a random id value that is different for every row (in a form similar to "tt19821") and the `episodes` collection has a field `episodeLink` which would be in the form "/title/tt19821/".

I would like to join these two tables (joining the `episodeLink` field with the corresponding `episodeLink` field) using pymongo.

```
pipeline = [{"$set": {"tconst": {"$regexFind": {"input": "$episodeLink", "regex": "/title/(.*?)/"}}}}, {"$merge": {"into": "ratings", "on": "tconst", "whenMatched": "merge", "whenNotMatched": "discard"}}]
client['data']['episodes'].aggregate(pipeline)
```

I got the following error for this code: How to overcome 'Cannot find index to verify that join fields will be unique' error using aggregate pipelines in pymongo. I'm not sure how i can make a column that has been set in the pipeline into a unique index?

Answer (score 0):

> 'Cannot find index to verify that join fields will be unique'

The error says you need to create an index on `on` value/property of the merge collection, which means create a unique index on `tconst` of collection `ratings`,

Execute below command in your database,

```
db.getCollection('ratings').createIndex({ tconst: 1 }, { unique: true })
```

There are a few issues in your query,

- `$regexFind` will result:

```
tconst: {
  "match" : "/title/tt19821/",
  "idx" : 0,
  "captures" : [ 
    "tt19821"
  ]
}
```

To access a specific match you need to use the below operation:

- `$let` to declare a variable and get first matched from `tconst.captures` using `$first`
- `$unset` `_id` to avoid the error "failed to update the matching document did you attempt to modify the _id or the shard key?"
- `$merge` as it is

```
pipeline = [
  {
    "$set": {
      "tconst": {
        "$let": {
          "vars": {
            "t": {
              "$regexFind": {
                "input": "$episodeLink",
                "regex": "/title/(.*?)/"
              }
            }
          },
          "in": { "$first": "$$t.captures" }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { "$unset": "_id" },
  {
    "$merge": {
      "into": "ratings",
      "on": "tconst",
      "whenMatched": "merge",
      "whenNotMatched": "discard"
    }
  }
]
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/FedDRm6VQGC)

Comment: Thank you for the help with setting tconst on the episode table, it was very useful! However I'm still getting the following error: 
PlanExecutor error during aggregation :: caused by :: $merge failed to update the matching document, did you attempt to modify the _id or the shard key?
Do you have any idea why this is?

Also do you know if there's a way to join these tables if there is duplicated tconst values on the ratings table so each of the duplicated values will merge with one episodeLink from the episode collection?

Comment: I forgot to mention that, I have updated the answer, you have to unset `_id` property.